# How to list all the items in a table with pagination

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to list all the items in a DynamoDB table with pagination, and here below is my attempt:

```
const tableName = "RecordingTable"

type Recording struct {
    ID string `dynamodbav:"id"`
    CreatedAt string `dynamodbav:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt string `dynamodbav:"updatedAt"`
    Duration int `dynamodbav:"duration"`
}

type RecordingRepository struct {
    ctx context.Context
    svc *dynamodb.Client
}

func NewRecordingRepository(ctx context.Context) (*RecordingRepository, error) {
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &RecordingRepository{ctx, dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg)}, nil
}

func (r *RecordingRepository) List(page int, size int) ([]Recording, error) {
    size32 := int32(size)
    queryInput := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
        Limit:     &size32,
    }

    recordings := []Recording{}
    queryPaginator := dynamodb.NewQueryPaginator(r.svc, queryInput)

    for i := 0; queryPaginator.HasMorePages(); i++ {
        result, err := queryPaginator.NextPage(r.ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        if i == page {
            if result.Count > 0 {
                for _, v := range result.Items {
                    recording := Recording{}
                    if err := attributevalue.UnmarshalMap(v, &recording); err != nil {
                        return nil, err
                    }
                    recordings = append(recordings, recording)
                }
            }
            break
        }
    }

    return recordings, nil
}
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error message:

```
api error ValidationException: Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.
```

But why should I specify a `KeyConditionExpression` when I want to get all the items? Is there another way to go or a workaround this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Query` does need your keys. It is meant to find *specific* items in your DynamoDB. To get *all* items in your DynamoDB, you need to use the `Scan` operation.

This should be easily fixed in your code.

Instead of `QueryInput` use [ScanInput](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb#ScanInput) and instead of `NewQueryPaginator` use [NewScanPaginator](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb#NewScanPaginator).

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced `QueryInput` with `ScanInput` and `QueryPaginator` with `ScanPaginator`.